# PHP on production not recognizing $_REQUEST from Angular 6 post

Tags: php, post, angular6

On my development environment, which is an older PHP 5.6.9, the following works just fine:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    $this->name = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['password'])) {
    $this->pass1 = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
}

if(!empty($_REQUEST['confirm_password'])) {
    $this->pass2 = trim($_REQUEST['confirm_password']);
} else {
  $this->temp_arr = array('msg' => 'You must enter a confirm password');
  echo json_encode($this->temp_arr); die();
}
```

However, on production, it is not seeing the $_REQUEST or $_POST and ends at the final conditional, which prints the JSON message that the user needs to input a confirm password.

If I try the following:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$this->name = $request->email;
$this->pass1 = $request->password;
$this->pass2 = $request->confirm_password;
// echo $password . " confirm: " . $confirm_password; die();
if(!empty($this->name)) {
    $this->name = trim($this->name);
}

if(!empty($this->pass1)) {
    $this->pass1 = trim($this->pass1);
}

if(!empty($this->pass2)) {
    $this->pass2 = trim($this->pass2);
} else {
  $this->temp_arr = array('msg' => 'You must enter a confirm password');
  echo json_encode($this->temp_arr); die();
}
 echo $this->pass1 . " confirm: " . $this->pass2; die();
```

Then php echoes pass1 and pass2.

Why would this work and the other does not? Is there a configuration in PHP.ini that I can turn on?

Before you ask, I do not know what version of PHP is running on the production server. There is something wrong with ssh and I am awaiting tech support's response. This is a brand new domain as of yesterday, brand new.

Update:
Spoke to soon, tech support just sent an email and I have ssh in. PHP is older than my version PHP 5.4.16

Another correction, the PHP CLI is 5.4.16, the web server PHP is 5.6.16 - phpinfo()

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to run away from both of those VERY old versions of PHP. Look for a new provider if that one gave you 5.4.16 by default. It's been end of life for more than 3 years now.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for replying, but I have been with these guys for over twenty years and they treat me very kind, which I do not find much of in businesses these days

Comment: Understood but they really aren't doing you any favors by providing a very very old version of PHP. Get a copy of the output of `phpinfo()` and add it to your question please.

Comment: @Dave thanks once more for replying. phpinfo() is pretty lengthy and it has been suggested in the past that some of my posts can be too long, but you can see it for yourself at the following - http://for-her.biz/mInfo.php

Comment: Something very strange is going on. That report shows 5.6.16 but the headers coming back show that the server is reporting 5.4.16 `Server 
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16`. Nothing else really jumps out at me though other than the very old levels of PHP being used.

Comment: @Dave there are many strange things going on with this web server. I just finished another ng build and now the images will not load - "cannot be displayed because of errors" - https://for-her.biz/unicorn-vortex-one-e-675x325.3778290e09d0254c5558.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188001/discussion-between-dave-and-kronus).